# Выбор предлога ИЗ / СРЕДИ + существительное /местоимение в родительном падеже

Tags: сравнение, предлоги

Здравствуйте. Объясните, пожалуйста, в каком случае при сравнении используется  предлог "ИЗ", а в каком "СРЕДИ". По каким критериям определяется выбор предлога?

ИЗ/СРЕДИ+СУЩ/МЕСТОИМЕНИЕ  В Р.П.

"Байкал-глубочайшее ИЗ озер."

"Этот роман - скучнейшая ИЗ всех книг."

"Книга - самый лучший ИЗ подарков."

"Его ответ - наименее правильный ИЗ всех."

"Его работа - самая лучшая СРЕДИ проектов."

"Сегодня ты самая красивая Среди нас."

ИЗ/СРЕДИ тех/всех+придаточное.

"Этот фильм худший ИЗ тех, что я видел."

"Он самый серьезный СРЕДИ всех, с кем я говорил."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Среди - 1) внутри пространства, 2) в числе других предметов, 3) среди других людей.

Из - 1) выделение одного предмета из  числа других.

2 знач. "среди" - синонимично предлогу "из" - одно выделяется среди других, из числа других. Они взаимозаменяемы, значит, отличаются только незначительным оттенком, не стоит раздумывать над выбором.

"Байкал - глубочайшее ИЗ озер" - выделяется из других озёр, можно сказать и "среди озёр".

"Этот роман - скучнейшая ИЗ всех книг" - выделяется, но и находится среди других книг.

"Книга - самый лучший ИЗ подарков" - выделяется из хороших.

"Его ответ - наименее правильный ИЗ всех" - выделяется из всех.

"Его работа - самая лучшая СРЕДИ проектов" - лучшая в числе других хороших работ.

"Сегодня ты самая красивая Среди нас" - смотрят на всех и выделяют лучшую среди других красивых.

"Этот фильм худший ИЗ тех, что я видел" - выбрали один плохой из всех.

"Он самый серьезный СРЕДИ всех, с кем я говорил" - по сравнению с другими самый серьёзный.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что форма с предлогом "ИЗ" имеет окончательный смысл (это абсолютный показатель), в то время как форма с предлогом СРЕДИ подразумевает изменение показателя при расширенном толковании.

Байкал-глубочайшее из озер (абсолютный показатель). Сравнить: "Байкал-глубочайшее среди озер (но моря и океаны глубже).

"Его работа - самая лучшая СРЕДИ проектов (представленных здесь, но не более).

Сегодня ты самая красивая среди нас (присутствующих здесь, входящих в наш круг, но не вообще).

Этот фильм худший ИЗ тех, что я видел (указан абсолютный показатель).

Он самый серьезный СРЕДИ всех, с кем я говорил (относительный показатель, предполагает, что, конечно, встречаются более серьезные люди).

Таким образом, выбор авторский и зависит от желания автора подчеркнуть относительность или абсолютность оценки.

Comment: "Байкал - глубочайшее среди озер (но моря и океаны глубже)" - мне видится надуманность. Кому придёт в голову сравнивать озеро и океан? Что "среди", что "из" - одинаково - в числе других озёр, из числа других озёр.

"Его работа - самая лучшая СРЕДИ проектов (представленных здесь, но не более)". А "из проектов" - разве всех проектов по стране? - тоже из представленных проектов. Не вижу разницы.

Comment: Выбор здесь делается не путем долгих раздумий, а скорее, на уровне интуиции. Можно предположить, что предлог ИЗ более характерен для книжного (научного, делового) стиля, когда требуется бОльшая точность и строгость выражений.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "среди" вместо "из" после прилагательного в  превосходной степени - это просторечье.

Comment: Да, вопрос требует проработки. Возможно, неточность значения предлога СРЕДИ придает ему если не просторечную, то разговорную стилевую окраску. Во всяком случае, не стоит утверждать, что предлоги тождественны, это слишком простое решение. Анализировать семантические особенности в каждом случае также вряд ли имеет смысл, хотя разная исходная семантика должна как-то сказаться на  употреблении предлогов. Скорее всего, следует различать их по стилю.

Answer (score -1):

Исправления

"Байкал - глубочайшее ИЗ озер." - выделяется из других озёр, НЕЛЬЗЯ "среди озёр". Но можно: Верхнее озеро самое большое СРЕДИ Великих озёр (это ГРУППА озёр).

"Его ответ - наименее правильный ИЗ всех." - ответ не умеет быть более-менее прав., он или прав., или неправ.

"Его работа - самая лучшая СРЕДИ проектов." - самая - здесь не нужна, нет противопоставления качества. Нужно: ИЗ проектов - их не кружок, не куча. Здесь выбор из ряда. Предлог сохраняет копрень *середина - круга, группы, кучи, толпы...

"Сегодня ты самая красивая Среди нас." - смотрят на всех и выделяют лучшую среди других красивых. Предл. СРЕДИ подчёркивает общность круга знакомых и почти нейтрален. ИЗ нас - выделяет одну, и если группе есть ещё женщины - предл. ИЗ унижает их.

"Он самый серьезный СРЕДИ всех, с кем я говорил." - только ИЗ. Здесь выделение одного из цепочки, но: Он самый серьёзный среди одноклассников.